# Touchpad barely works after updates

Tags: mouse, touchpad

Hardware: Dell Laptitude E6410:AlpsPS/2 ALPS Dualpoint TouchPad
Ubuntu 14.04.2

Did updates this morning and haven't used my touchpad until now. Just started using the touchpad and it barely works.

When I say it barely works, here's what I mean.
- Scrolling vertical and horizontal works perfectly
- Clicking via the touchpad or the touchpad buttons works
- Using the touchpad to move the cursor doesn't work

The touchpad barely moves. My sensitive is the same as before, and even moving it around does nothing. I have a nub in the middle of the keyboard and that works fine. Problem with the nub is I can't use it nearly as effectively. I'm very slow and I need my touchpad to work.

Unfortunately, I don't know what updated this morning. There were 4-5 packages, but I'm not entirely sure which ones they were. Disabling the touchpad and reenable it doesn't fix the issue. Restarting Ubuntu doesn't fix the issue either.

Comment: Did you disable it using the terminal?

Comment: It makes sense to specify which Ubuntu version you use, what hardware, etc.

Comment: For testing, I disabled it via the GUI. I just tried disabling and enabling via the terminal and same result. Once I enable it, the mouse will barely move. Sometimes it will move a decent amount of pixels, for the most part it barely moves any pixels.

Comment: Added the hardware and version to the main post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The touchpad driver is in the Linux kernel. You probably upgraded the kernel and there is some regression there. Try to boot with a previous kernel using grub menu and test, if touchpad works.

If this is the case you can upgrade your kernel to 3.16, which is default in 14.04.2 by running

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-utopic
```

It may help, if regression is not that fundamental and appeared accidentally in some kernel release.

If it still does not work, then it makes sense to report a bug at launchpad by running

```
ubuntu-bug linux
```

Or if you previously installed some specific touchpad driver and upgraded the kernel, the driver may not build.

You can find this by running

```
dkms status
```

There were some alps touchpad drivers in dkms format, that could be found in the net.

Comment: Thank you, this was the issue. I rebooted into GRUB and selected an older kernel and the touchpad is back to standard operation. I'm currently using 3.13.0-44-generic and was at version 3.13.0-52-generic. Somewhere in between broke the driver for the touchpad.

Comment: You can try to upgrade kernel to default in 14.04.2 I added to the answer.

Comment: I don't have any specific driver installed. With regards to the kernel, I just upgraded and same issue. I'll try filing a bug once I get back to an area where I can use a mouse.

Comment: You can boot now with a kernel, where touchpad works.